# How to check if a site that has HTTPS URLS has HTTP URLS active too?

Tags: http, https

I have a website that uses the HTTPS protocol. I need to check if there are non-HTTPS pages active on the site. Is there a way to identify them without crawling the entire site?

Answer (score 0):

Load your website in an IDE (like PhpStorm, etc), and search for reference "http://".

When you develop your website and wants to refer an external file on other domain, and always use the same protocol, use "//" as protocol : instead of `http://example.com/myfile.txt`, use `//example.com/myfile.txt`